# Connection String Works from Mac but not directly in Parallels

Tags: connection-string

So I have a connection string from a .NET Core application attempting to connect to a database that is sat on a Parallels Windows VM. When I spin the app up using Visual Studio for Mac it can connect with no issues, I use the same connection string from the VM using Visual Studio from Windows and it won't connect to the database.

Here's the connection string:

```
Server=10.211.55.3,5171;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=<password>;Initial Catalog=Hub.Database;
```

The IP address it's connecting to there is the IP of Windows VM. Not sure why this would work in one place but not another.

Error message I'm getting is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified